# PHP's imagecreatefromstring function not working on Amazon Linux Server

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have created a script in which a i have to create a image at runtime using a 64bitencoded string .i m using imagecreatefromstring function of PHP but it works in my Windows XAMPP based PHP , but not on my cloud side applications which i deployed on Amazon cloud running SUSE version of Linux.

Can u give me any suggestion to overcome the problem.
Or is there any other function which is capable to create the image from the encoded string passed to it.

Thanks in adv

I am using following code

```
<?php
         require ('../dbconfig/dbConfig.php');

    $gameId = $_POST["gameId"];
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $imagedata =  $_POST['imagedata'];

    $uploaddir = './../blogdata/i/'; 

    $countSql =  mysql_query("select  max(_id) as fileName  from blog_data ");

    while($rowCommentData = mysql_fetch_assoc($countSql))
    {
        $num = $rowCommentData["fileName"];
        $file = ++$num.".png";
        $filedb = $uploaddir .$file;
    }


   /* $imagedata= 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
               . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
               . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
               . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';*/

    $imagedata= base64_decode($imagedata);

    if(($img = @imagecreatefromstring($imagedata)) !== FALSE) 
    {

            if(imagepng($img,$filedb))
            {       
                    imagedestroy($img);

                    $sql="Insert into blog_data (game_id,text,type,username)".
                                   "Values('$gameId','$file','i','$username')";

                    $result=mysql_query($sql);

                    if($result == 1)
                    {
                        echo $file; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "error2";
                    }
            } 
            else {
                echo "error1";
            }               
                   }
    else
    { 
         echo "error0";
    }
```

?>

By running PHP info there i got this information
[image]

Comment: Please show some code and example data.

Comment: It fails not because it requires Windows, but because it requires the GD library.

Comment: are you sure your server has the gd extension installed and enabled? Please check the `phpinfo` output and look for the GD extension

Comment: hey man how use yum command to install the Gd package there. i have downloaded the package there.

Comment: My advice - do NOT use `@`. You would see an error message outputted or saved to log if you would not prefix non-existent function `imagecreatefromstring()` with `@`. Suppressing outputting error messages should be done by setting `dislpay_errors` to `false`.

Comment: sudo yum install php5-gd didn't solve the problem. I have to exact same problem. Could you please explain how you solved it? I have one php file and it worked in a school server. This image methods encoding you are using. But in amazon server it is not working. Could you please tell me how to solved this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP needs to have the libgd extension installed and loaded. Check phpinfo() if it's there. You probably can install it via yum. The package should be called php5-gd

Comment: hey Andreas from where i can get this package named php5-gd

Comment: I'm not very familar with SuSe. You probably can find the package at their ftp server, but I guess SuSe has some automatic way to install distribution packages as well. This should have some more explanations on how to find and install packages: http://en.opensuse.org/Package_management

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it seems that you dont have the GD extension installed. Please check the `phpinfo` output and look for the GD extension

Comment: I have the same problem and installing GD extension didn't solve the problem (sudo yum install php5-gd).

Comment: I checked the phpinfo. But I already the GD extension installed but getting the same error as the questioner. (php -i takes you to the phpinfo page) GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.3.11
T1Lib Support => enabled
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.49
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled

Answer (score 0):

You will need root access to the server, which I don't think you get with Amazon's cloud service. You will need to recompile php with --with-gd flag.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean?